# ¿Cuál es la historia detrás de tu pregunta?

Tags: discusión, concursos

Agradezco a *the-breaker* por la traducción.

---

Hace nueve años estuve trabajando en mi primer proyecto Golang. El proyecto era pequeño, yo era joven y demasiado seguro de mí mismo: "¿Por qué debería gastar mi tiempo escribiendo código para desplegar la aplicación en el servidor? ¿Cierto? ¡No hay razón! ¡Nunca debería cometer errores en solo 3 comandos para actualizar la aplicación!".

Una tarde, al llegar a casa, empecé a trabajar en mi aplicación. Acabé otra versión de la aplicación hacia la media noche. Estando un poco cansado (estudio, trabajo, proyecto), ensamblé la aplicación y comencé a implementar la actualización en el servidor:

```
...
scp -P … -i … user@host:/path/to/server_folder
ssh …
```

Me logueé en el servidor como invitado, autorizado como un usuario con privilegios. (Mientras tanto se hizo más tarde). Luego empecé a escribir comandos muy comunes para mí:

```
...
cd /path/to/server_folder/my_cool_go_app/
rm -rf . /
```

Por alguna razón, luego de la ultima linea, la terminal no retorno al modo de entrada, sino que se colgó en el comando `rm`... qué extraño… "¡Espera un minuto! ¡Maldición, hay un espacio entre el punto y la barra!"

[image]

Lo peor es que ese era el servidor de producción. Bueno, esa noche entendí por qué necesitamos respaldos (backups) y cómo rápidamente puedo desplegar uno. También escribí todos los códigos de despliegue.

Desde aquella historia, se me ocurrió una pregunta: [How to avoid typos when performing the rm command?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1017949/6) (*¿Cómo evitar errores tipográficos cuando ejecutas el comando rm?*)

---

¿De qué va todo esto? Es sobre un concurso interesante para la comunidad =)

#### Concurso "La mejor historia detrás de una pregunta técnica".

Cada uno de vosotros tenéis una divertida, triste o simplemente inusual historia relacionada con la programación. Creo que sería interesante compartir historias con nuestros colegas. Para hacerlo aún más entretenido, vamos a compartir las historias en un formato de concurso. Las reglas del concurso son extremadamente simples:

1. Primero necesitas publicar una pregunta técnica en el sitio oficial.
2. Luego publica una respuesta en Meta (sobre la pregunta) con la historia relacionada a la pregunta que hiciste en el sitio oficial. (Por favor, no olvides mencionar la pregunta en la historia, para que todo esté en la misma página).

¡Eso es todo!

Los ganadores serán los 3 usuarios que obtengan la puntuación máxima total consistente en la puntuación en el sitio oficial + la suma de las puntuaciones de todas las respuestas a esta (sin contar votos negativos y respuestas eliminadas) + la puntuación de la respuesta con la historia. **Enviaremos geniales premios a los ganadores.**

El concurso empieza el 1 de septiembre y termina el 30 de septiembre. El cómputo de los resultados se hará el 10 de octubre para dar oportunidad a aquellos que publiquen sus historias a finales de septiembre.

**Por favor comparte tu historia con la comunidad**

Casi lo olvido: si tienes muchas historias, siéntete libre de compartirlas todas. Cada respuesta es una historia =)

Comment: Se ve interesante (_looks interesting_), me imagino que solo participan preguntas publicadas en septiembre.

Comment: Correcto, según la publicación, los aportes deben de tener fechas entre el primero y último día de septiembre.

Comment: Lástima que sólo cuenten las preguntas publicadas en septiembre... una de mis preguntas tiene una historia interesantísima detrás, nada menos que la historia de este sitio: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1 (^__^)

Comment: @Konamiman Podrías publicarla igual, sabiendo q no cuenta. Me dio intriga saber la historia detrás de la primera pregunta del sitio.

Comment: @Konamiman ¡Por favor, comparte tu historia! =)  Muchas comunidades internacionales decidieron que querían incluir publicaciones antiguas en el concurso.

Answer (score 13):

Fuera de concurso y a petición popular, he aquí la historia de mi pregunta. Pongo la URL en vez del título porque ahí está la gracia de la misma: `https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1`.

Sí, 1. Esa fue la primera pregunta en el sitio Stack Overflow en español.

El tema es que a finales de octubre de 2015 y tras ayudar con las traducciones, Juan me "reclutó" como tester y me dio acceso al sitio, que aún estaba muy verde (creo que incluso en "pre-alfa"), y en cuanto entré vi algo que creía prohibido por las leyes de la física: un sitio completamente vacío, sin una sola pregunta.

Así que pensé, bueno, hay que darle un poco de vidilla a esto pero no quiero publicar una pregunta tonta tipo "eso es una prueba" que acabe siendo borrada. Así que en vez de eso, busqué una pregunta que yo hubiera formulado anteriormente en el sitio en inglés, que yo mismo hubiera respondido también, y que fuera de cierta calidad. La encontré, la traduje y la publiqué. Y ahí está: [La creación manual de un alias de ruta con un DirectRouteProvider personalizado causa un error "Multiple actions were found that match the request"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1)

En mi opinión, además de demostrar que el sitio funcionaba, el valor de esa pregunta es que inició el debate (que se ha demostrado nada trivial) sobre si se deben permitir traducciones de preguntas/respuestas del sitio en inglés en este nuestro hispanohablante sitio.

Comment: Seria interesante de verdad verte mas activo en el sitio en español!

Comment: Me paso por el sitio a diario, pero pocas veces encuentro una pregunta a la que sea capaz de responder

Comment: tambien nos podrias explicar [El comentario mas famoso del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4603/por-qu%c3%a9-nan-nan#comment8434_4603)

Answer (score 9):

Mi pregunta es :
[Realizar backup incremental o diferencial en MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56041/realizar-backup-incremental-o-diferencial-en-mysql)

---

**Capitulo # 1. El Novato y su EGO**

Cuando empece a desarrollar mi EGO de Programador estaba en las nube (creo que el cloud computing nacio gracias a mi), llego la era del pingüino , pertenecía a communidad de GNU/Linux mi hermano me enseño mucho tan solo tenia 18 años, era muy activo en los [IRC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat).

En mi primer trabajo al tercer dia , me dijeron que hiciera algun cambio en la base de datos el Sistema Operativo donde estaba la base de datos era Ubuntu; pues me fui el IRC de Ubuntu y pedi ayuda, algunas personas gustosamente ; luego llego otro usuario y me dijo que ejecutara el comando:

```
sudo rm -rf --.*
```

Jack el novato muy juicioso copio y pego :O (tiene un error intencional por si algun otro usuario quiera intentarlo)

[image: Jack no lo hagas]

Pues mantuve mi empleo pero me quitaron permisos en los servidores , mi compañero Senior  mi [sensei](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensei) Silmer (su nombre)  a quien le debo aprendizajes tanto profesional como personal , tenia una DB bajo la manga.

Para no dejar cabo suelto ¿Porque un Usuario de la comunidad me paso ese comando?, Era un usuario **Debían** y detestaba cualquier distro basadas en ese sistemas que no eran completamente libres

<sub>Por eso a todos los usuarios les digo en StackOverflow solemos ayudar, pero siempre existira algun radical que cree en sus principios</sub>

---

**Capitulo # 2 El Chavo lo hizo otra vez!**

Ya había tenido algunas pifias pero pasaron desapercibidas Pero transcurrido, Me toco realizar un Respaldo al servidor de Producción y llevarlo al de QA, Un Compañero me dice, espera en la noche y lo haces, le dije esto no tiene ciencia y bueno ya se imaginan lo que hice eran las 9:00AM ...

Me declaro culpable, lo  hice todo al contrario, Pero fue porque Cambiaron las IPs y pues me confundí, nuevamente lo arruine , se perdieron 3 Horas de Producción de La empresa, mas la reconstrucción de los Pedidos que no fueron despachados, El equipo de Informática eramos muy unidos, pues hable con la verdad y dije mi error; ellos inventaron un nuevo problema y mi cabeza no fue degollada, Pero fui bautizado como:

1. EL Chavo del Ocho (aun mantengo contactos y sigo siendo el Chavito)
2. The Matrix
3. EL SQLTOR (TERMINATOR)
4. [Jaimito](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaimito)
5. El terror de las Bases de Datos(Apodo colocado por un Venezolano Comentaba que era un programa en Venezuela).

   Chistes como : Gracias a ti salieron canciones que dicen [No te olvides de poner el Where en el Delete From](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_cVJgIz_Cs).

Me hicieron mucho Bullying, bueno, tambien se puede decir que me Recordaron lo que no se debe hacer

y por supuesto. Hasta la Vista..**DB**aby

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Capitulo # 3 Quemando se Aprende a Planchar!**

En esta oportunidad tenia que hacer una migración de aproximadamente 37 Bases de datos!, parecia que tome el [Delorean](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeLorean_DMC-12) a lo Marty McFly(JackMcFLy) y fui al pasado  con el Doc
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero esta vez aprendí , y pensé si existe alguna forma de realizar un buen backup de base de datos, mi solución claro podemos hacer backups incremental o diferencial.. pero.... ¿MySQL tiene eso? Investiguemos!, si lo tiene pero es pago, como puedo hacer esto sin pagar... preguntemos en stackoverflow alguien me ayudara!..

Conseguí la ayuda hice la migración sin problemas(de base de datos) fue un éxito la migración!

> Moraleja: Toda la vida seremos Programadores Junior, basta con
>   trabajar bajo presión y te darás cuenta

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Muy bonita historia =)

Answer (score 8):

Hice la pregunta [Como Desordenar, Mezclar, Barajar un Array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/296944/como-desordenar-mezclar-barajar-un-array) en base a la siguiente historia:

A finales del 2012, ya estaba por terminar el semestre en la Universidad, tome la materia de Taller de Programación (sigla INF-143) con un docente (lo llamaré Lic. JF) el cual era algo estricto pero que ya conocía como trabajaba.

Dos meses atrás, como trabajo final nos pidió hacer un juego que muestre el funcionamiento de algunos algoritmos, me toco *backtracking* (vuelta hacia atrás). Decidí hacer un juego de un laberinto que se resolvía con *backtraking*, lo teníamos que hacer en Java.

Para hacer el mapa del laberinto tenia una matriz, la cual se generaba a partir de un numero **n** que indicaba sus dimensiones, en un principio estaba llena de caracteres que representaban paredes, y para generar el camino empleaba un *array* con números, los cuales con ayuda de una eucarística marcaban que casillas iban a componer los caminos.

El laberinto tenia que generarse de forma aleatoria, para mostrar que el *backtracking* funcionaba, así que pensé en una forma de generarlo a partir de un *array* con números desordenados.

Busque en Internet un algoritmo para desordenar un *array* en Java, encontré uno en una pagina, los comentarios dijeron que funcionaba, lo probé y funciono. No entendía la lógica de como desordenaba los números, solo lo puse en mi programa y continué haciendo el juego.

Cuando ya lo tenia avanzado, hacia varias pruebas con números como 20 y 25 y funcionaba bastante bien, luego deje de trabajar esa parte y me puse a investigar como hacerle una interfaz gráfica (ya que solo se mostraba en consola).

Así era como se veía en la consola.

```html
dim de n = 20
 M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M
 M O         #                   # #       M
 M   # # #       #   #   # # #       # #   M
 M     #   # # #   # #   #     # #     #   M
 M #   #             #     # # #   #   #   M
 M     #   # # #   #   #   #     #     #   M
 M   # #   #     #     #   # #   #   #     M
 M   #     #   #     #     # #   #   #   # M
 M   #   #   #     # #   #     #     #     M
 M   #     #     #   #     #       #   #   M
 M   # #     #   # #   #   # # # #   #     M
 M   # # # # #       # #   #         #   # M
 M     #       # #   #     # # # #       # M
 M #       #         #   #       # #   # # M
 M # # # #   # # #   #   # # #             M
 M #       # #       #         # # #   #   M
 M     #       #   #   # # #   #   #   #   M
 M   # # # #     #     #   #   # # #     # M
 M   # #   # #     #       #   #     #   # M
 M       #     #     # #   #   #   # #   # M
 M # #       #   #         #   #         # M
 M M M M M M M M M M M M M M S M M M M M M M
```

Me pase el resto del tiempo haciendo el juego mas llamativo, y deje de ocuparme de la parte lógica.

Llego el día de la entrega final, nos reunimos todos en el laboratorio, cada uno tenia que mostrar su proyecto, ya tenia listo el programa, solo teníamos que mostrárselo al Lic., si funcionaba podíamos irnos, de otro modo teníamos hasta que termine el periodo para corregirlo. Estaba confiado en que iba a funcionar, incluso ya se lo había mostrado antes.

El momento en que llego donde estaba, le mostré el juego y funciono con 25, pero luego me dijo *"ponle 100"*, ahí fue cuando paso algo extraño, el laberinto solo se generaba hasta cierta parte, y luego dejaba el resto como pared, se veía horrendo, me dijo *"tienes hasta que acabe el periodo para corregirlo"*.

Me puse a investigar el código y halle el problema, **el algoritmo no desordenaba todo el array**, a parir de en medio se mostraba de esta forma:

```
29,14,59,61,60,62,63,64,65,67,66,68,69,70...
```

No sabia que hacer, trate de corregirlo, probé cambiando algunas variables pero nada, no entendía como funcionaba así que no podía arreglarlo.

Ya había pasado una hora, ya algunos compañeros se habían ido, el laboratorio se vaciaba y aun no encontraba como corregir el código. El docente regreso donde estaba, vio que aun no corría el juego, me dijo *"he visto que has trabajado, puedo ponerte la mitad de la nota"*, pero no podía aceptar la mitad después de esforzarme tanto haciendo el juego, le dije que iba a quedarme arreglando el código.

Ya solo faltaban 20 minutos para que acabe el periodo, quedaban pocos en el laboratorio, no quedaba mucho tiempo, estaba por rendirme, cuando se me ocurrió una forma de salvar el momento, podría ser peligroso, pero puede funcionar, hice lo siguiente, comente las lineas del algoritmo que mezclaba el *array* y puse otro array desordenado a mano para que el juego funcione.

Cuando lo termine llame al Lic. se lo mostré una vez, temía que me diga que se lo muestre una segunda, ya que podía notar que era el mismo laberinto. Por suerte se convenció con la primera y me dejo ir con la nota completa, ya estaba mas tranquilo.

Tiempo después corregí el juego y le agregue un método que si funcionaba.

> Y así fue como aprendí que es importante hacer pruebas exhaustivas de
>   los programas que haces y verificar bien que el código que encuentras
>   por Internet funcione.

Aquí hay unas capturas del juego, con el algoritmo que falla y el que funciona bien:

[image: laberintos]

Gracias por leer.

Answer (score 6):

Tengo una historia relacionada a la pregunta

[¿Como obtener números separados de un string C#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291808/como-obtener-n%c3%bameros-separados-de-un-string-c)

Esto sucedió en los tiempos cuando cursaba la universidad, estaba haciendo mis pasantías en la misma universidad donde estudiaba, estábamos configurando la funcionalidad de un sistema de evaluaciones,  y lo que menciono en la pregunta

> **obtener los numeros por separado, es decir {24, 25}**

era para asignar los días de evaluaciones de los estudiantes a distancia.

Sin embargo al ser nuevo en el mundo de la programación me fallo un split que hice a la cadena y en vez de poner la fecha de evaluación para el

**24/01/2013 y 25/01/2013**

se coloco la fecha

**2/01/2013 y 2/01/2013**

ya que en la base de datos se guardaba en diferentes columnas, el dia, el mes y el año, por lo que no me di cuenta del error.

Afortunadamente el desarrollador a cargo del área se dio cuenta del problema y lo soluciono antes del día de las evaluaciones, sino los cerca de 5 mil estudiantes hubieran generado reclamos por no tener evaluaciones disponibles.

En si lo considero como un error de novato hablando tecnicamente, pero en general en el proceso de evaluaciones hubiera causado problemas en la universidad XD.

Answer (score 5):

Acabo de ver esta publicación en meta y tengo una `historia detrás de la pregunta`, la pongo porque se que aportara mucho culturalmente.

[¿Como puedo obtener una barra de rutas en eclipse?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/296603/3834)

Estaba en mi primer trabajo codificando después de una noche en la cual me había desvelado, todo esta bien en ese día hasta que regrese de comer. Me dio el [Mal del puerco](https://www.eluniversal.com.mx/ciencia-y-salud/salud/por-que-ocurre-el-mal-del-puerco-la-ciencia-lo-explica) y empece a cabecear con el mouse en la mano. En una de esas di unos clics y cuando reaccione apareció la barra motivo de mi pregunta. No supe como salio pero aportaba gran funcionalidad (sobre todo cuando copias clases o proyectos). Le pregunte a todos en el trabajo, busque en internet y nadie me supo decir. En esa época no existía SOes así que aunque seguí usando la barra y me quede con la duda y se me olvido el tema.

Tiempo después me cambie de trabajo, deje de usar eclipse y en mi nuevo trabajo aprendí [Oracle APEX](https://apex.oracle.com/es/), ahí en un desarrollo hicimos una pagina y al ultimo me pidieron que le pusiera `breadcrumbs` y que funcionaran. Uno de mis compañeros en el desarrollo ya sabia lo que habían pedido y me explico:" `Breadcrumb` es "migaja de pan" y se les llama así a la ruta que seguiste para llegar a cierta pagina. Tiene ese nombre debido al cuento de [Hansel y Gretel](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hansel_y_Gretel) donde dejan migas de pan para internarse en el bosque y encontrar el camino de regreso".

En Oracle Apex los `breadcrumbs` son fáciles de agregar y hacerlos funcionar pero pueden convertirse en tu peor pesadilla, ya que en ocasiones tienes que borrar páginas que los tienen y empiezan a quedar `breadcrumbs` huérfanos que provocan comportamientos extraños y siempre es fácil olvidarse de borrarlos. En fin, el desarrollo salio y tiempo después me volví a cambiar de trabajo.

En mi nuevo trabajo ya usaba eclipse de nuevo y en un desarrollo me pidieron ayudarle a un compañero en una pagina, después de que me explico, me dijo: "también le pones estas rutas" y me las señalo. Entonces yo respondí: ¡Ah!, los `breadcrumbs`. Y el me contesto tan asombrado y con una cara como si yo fuera el mayor crack de la programación: "TU SI SABES COMO SE LLAMAN" y le conté de mi experiencia con Oracle APEX.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de eso me puse a usar eclipse y dije:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

"Esperen un momento esa es la barra que estaba buscando". Así que me puse a picarle al eclipse y encontré `show in breadcrumbs` 5 años después. Uní los puntos como dijo [Steve jobs en su discurso](https://youtu.be/HHkJEz_HdTg).

Después de eso cada vez que yo decía `breadcrumbs` todos ponían cara como sí les hubiera provocado un orgasmo mental. Algo así como cuando los que hablamos español escuchamos hablar francés.

Tiempo después descubrí que en Francia a estos menús les conocen como el [Hilo de Ariadne](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miga_de_pan_(inform%C3%A1tica)) haciendo referencia al hilo que Ariadna le da a Teseo para que entre al laberinto, mate al minotauro y pueda salir del laberinto.

Comment: Horas perdidas en hacer q esos malditos `Breadcrumb ` de apex , funcionen como tienen q funcionar. Lo de Hansel y Gretel, lo termine asociando, asi como en tu historia, cuando me dijeron q significaba la palabra. Calculo q puse la misma cara de Fry mientras lo pensaba xD.

Comment: ¡Bonita historia! =)

Answer (score 3):

Una historia que casi termina en muertes

[ngcordova sqlite no funciona en android 6 o superiores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74415/ngcordova-sqlite-no-funciona-en-android-6-0-o-superior)

Cuando estaba preparando todo para exponer mi tesis de grado, los últimos 7 días de ea semana, todo fue una locura. Sobre esta tesis, la cual tuve muchas preguntas y dudas en el momento de programar, ya sean errores complejos o cosas sencillas, como la que una vez me paso como querer saltarme lo que significa tener una llave primaria y querer repetir esta, el cual muchos usuarios me ayudaron aquí con sus respuesta, tuve algo que casi me infarta a solo dos días de ir a exponer.

El proyecto era una app móvil que era el complemento del vortal para que los estudiantes y docentes vieran sus notas, listas de estudiantes, horarios, entre muchas cosas mas, la app fue desarrollada en Ionic 1.x el cual esta basado en Angular Js (por ende Ionic también). Pasaba que siempre los frameworks sacan versiones nuevas y en una de esa llego una actualización, y yo sin perder tiempo, hice dicho *update*.

Confiado de lo que todo estaba bien, mi compañero de trabajo me dice, prueba la app en mi teléfono nuevo a ver como va, para es entonces solo la probaba en un **Alcatel Idol X** con **Android 4.4** y en un teléfono con 5.0 o 5.1, cuando la probé en uno con 6.1, no cargaba la información, asumí que era un error en la API que consultaba la **DB** que estaba en el servidor, revisaba el llamado y traía la información normal, allí empece a preocuparme.

[image: preocupacion]

Estuve todo ese día buscando cual podría ser el error, hasta que al final un día antes de exponer realice la pregunta, y era lo que pensaba un tipo nuevo de creación y alojamiento de la **DB** de **SQLite** en el dispositivo móvil, entonces, volvió el espíritu al cuerpo.

[image: relax]

Comment: no entendí, ¿por que casi termina en muertes?

Comment: Por que si no estuviera la app móvil para el día del proyecto de grado, el director del proyecto, nos hubiese matado por tener dicho fallo el día de la presentación de la tesis.