# Las "mejores" historias detrás de preguntas que hemos formulado

Tags: discusión, concursos

Muchas gracias a [@Marc](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/50182/marc) por la traducción.

---

Una pregunta en Stack Overflow es sólo la punta de un iceberg. Tal y como lo veo, incluso una simple pregunta en el sitio puede estar precedida de una larga serie de intentos fallidos y búsquedas dolorosas de nuevas formas de resolver un problema (y a veces conversaciones difíciles con el jefe). Por ejemplo, una vez eliminé todo el contenido del servidor de producto con el comando `rm -rf . /*` (hice un error tipográfico, un espacio entre `.` y `/`), que causó la pregunta «[¿Cómo evitar errores tipográficos al eliminar un directorio en la terminal? (SOru)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1017949/6)».

A lo largo del mes de septiembre, [los usuarios han estado compartiendo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4306/10) las historias que precedieron a sus preguntas en Stack Overflow en español. ¡Muchas gracias a todos los que habéis participado!

Según los resultados, el mayor número de votos (una historia + pregunta y todas las respuestas) los obtuvieron:

- [JackNavaRow: Realizar backup incremental o diferencial en MySQL](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4354/10)
- [Juan Pinzón: ¿Como obtener números separados de un string C#?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4322/10)
- [abrahamhs: ¿Como puedo obtener una barra de rutas en eclipse?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4357/10)

Para mí todas las historias son muy interesantes. Invito a todos los que no las han visto a leerlas.

Publicación sobre el concurso en MSE “[What is the story behind your question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334861/what-is-the-story-behind-your-question)”

¡El concurso ha terminado pero no nos impide divertirnos un poco! Siéntete libre de compartir tu historia ahora mismo en [MSOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4306/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-historia-detr%C3%A1s-de-tu-pregunta) o en [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334861/what-is-the-story-behind-your-question).

Comment: Que es lo que han ganado? What is the reward?

Comment: ¡Enhorabuena a los 3!

Comment: solo dire esto: "si es una remera y una taza  la presumiré a alguien, no dare su nombre pero es cierto moderador Argentino y en su imagen de perfil esta el y su niño"

Comment: Felicidades a todos, interesantes historias. What is the reward?, @JackNavaRow alcancé 100,000 y me dijeron que esperara ya que al parecer no había productos "in stock" :-(.

Comment: @Jorgesys tristemente comparto tu situación: esperando respuesta ...

Comment: Nobleza obliga, Nicolás, en su momento, me hizo llegar una muy linda remera producto del anterior desafío, no dudo que habrá algún presente para los ganadores (Felicitaciones!).

Comment: Leyendo las reglas del concurso, se vee especificado que sólo cuentan las historias de las preguntas publicadas entre las fechas puestas en el concurso (es decir, todo Setiembre de 2019). ¿Se cambió esto más adelante? ¿Dónde está publicado?

Comment: @Marc [Nicolas dejo un comentario en la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4306/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-historia-detr%c3%a1s-de-tu-pregunta#comment17944_4306)

Comment: @x3k_js Sabremos la respuesta después de que los ganadores obtengan su botín =)

Comment: ¡Felicitaciones a los ganadores! =)

Comment: @JackNavaRow Okey, omitía esa información (en la pregunta había comentado que sólo las publicadas en Setiembre, por eso me confundí), Felicidades a los ganadores!

Comment: Si llego a saber que se podían usar preguntas antiguas me hubiera inventado una buena historia XD